# What Does the WAIT_BLOCKED Thread State Mean?

Tags: android, trace, lttng, thread-state, blocked-threads

I was analyzing lttng trace for AudioTrack thread, so at the time of glitch it shows thread state as `WAIT_BLOCKED`. Can anyone please tell what is the meaning of thread state `WAIT_BLOCKED`. Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8qqA.png)

Comment: orange bar in AudioTrack thread shows WAIT_BLOCKED

Answer (score 0):

`WAIT_BLOCKED` means that the thread has been scheduled out for being blocked on something, as opposed to a thread that would've been scheduled out due to preemption, in which case the state would be `WAIT_FOR_CPU`.

By itself, it doesn't tell us what exactly the thread is waiting for. It might be disk I/O or something else, you'd need to look at the context before and after the thread is in this state to figure that out.